# wordpress duplicator renaming web.config to web.config.orig

Tags: wordpress, iis

I am using ***WordPress 4.6.2***, with ***Duplicator plugin 1.1.16***. my OS is *Windows server 2012 - IIS 8.5.*

i have custom IIS rules for each website there different **web.config** files for each website

every time i get a WP package for deployment, in the middle of the WP installation process (using the package that was created by the **duplicator plugin**) the existing **web.config** files gets renamed to **web.config.orig** and the installation process gets paused (getting 405 error page), to fix that i am renaming the file to **web.config** and then refreshing the page it sometimes continues and sometimes it starts from the beginning.

any solutions, recommendation on what to do so that the **web.config** file will not be touched by the installation process ?

Answer (score 2):

In `installer.php` file, Duplicator Plugin forces renaming of web.config file. I have solved the trouble by commenting/erasing some lines on this file.

```
// @copy('web.config', "web.config.{$timeStamp}.orig");
// @unlink('web.config');
// @file_put_contents('web.config', "<!-- Reset by Duplicator Installer.  Original can be found in web.config.{$timeStamp}.orig -->");
```

And installation works correctly.